# Angular 2/5 get the value of a dynamic form

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic, ngfor

I'm trying to get the value of a form which contains a dynamic number of resources that come from the database. For each resource I want to affect the value of 3 parameters C, I, and A, but the form group always returns the value of the last resource.

desired return object is for example:

```
dataToSubmit = {

recource1 : {
             c:1,
             i:2,
             a:3,
         } ,

recource2 : {
             c:0,
             i:2,
             a:1, 
         },

recource3 : {
             c:3,
             i:0,
             a:1, 
         }

}
```

that's the html code that I tried:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper *ngIf=" anything == true" [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
    <form [formGroup]="cia" name="ciaform">
        <mat-step  *ngFor="let resource of resourcesarray" >
            <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ resource }}</ng-template>
            
            
            <h2>c</h2>
            <mat-select  formControlName="c" placeholder="score" >
                <mat-option [value]="0">
              0 (not classified)
            </mat-option>
                <mat-option [value]="1">
              1
            </mat-option>
                <mat-option [value]="2">
              2
            </mat-option>
                <mat-option [value]="3">
              3
            </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            
            
            <h2>I</h2>
            <mat-select formControlName="i" placeholder="score" >
                <mat-option [value]="0">
                  0 (not classified)
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option [value]="1">
                  1
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option [value]="2">
                  2
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option [value]="3">
                  3
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            
            
            <h2>A</h2>
            <mat-select formControlName="a" placeholder="score" >
                <mat-option [value]="0">
                      0 (not classified)
                    </mat-option>
                <mat-option [value]="1">
                      1
                    </mat-option>
                <mat-option [value]="2">
                      2
                    </mat-option>
                <mat-option [value]="3">
                      3
                    </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <button *ngIf="resourcesarray.indexOf(resource) !=0" mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext >Next</button>
        </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
        You are now done.
        
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
            <button mat-button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

currently the returned value of cia variable is { c: 1 , i: 2 , a: 3 }

Comment: You need create a FormArray -but the value will be an array, not an object with property "resource1,resource2.." or create a FormGroup with formGroup with the name "resource1","resource2"...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to have an unique name for your formControlName attributes, so instead of "c" for example, if the resource object has a name property, you could have [formControlName]="resource.name".